# PHP in_array() not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an `if` statment below that checks if a value is present in an array and adds it in there if it's not.
Apparently even if the value is in the array, it triggers it again.

As far as I understand, it should only display 1 of each value, because it will only trigger 3 times, like this:

```
Digital Photography -> 0
Step by Step Macintosh Training -> 0
How to become a Powerful Speaker -> 0
```

The code:

```
if (!in_array($unit['course_name'], $courseList)) {

  $courseList[$unit['course_name']]['name'] = $unit['course_name'];
  $courseList[$unit['course_name']]['seconds'] = 0;
  echo $courseList[$unit['course_name']]['name'] . ' -> ' . $courseList[$unit['course_name']]['seconds'];
  echo "<BR>";

}
```

But it outputs:

```
Digital Photography -> 0
Step by Step Macintosh Training -> 0
Step by Step Macintosh Training -> 0
Step by Step Macintosh Training -> 0
How to become a Powerful Speaker -> 0
How to become a Powerful Speaker -> 0
```

Here is the `var_dump($unit)`:

```
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" [0]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" ["course_name"]=> string(19) "Digital Photography" [1]=> string(19) "Digital Photography" ["unit_id"]=> string(3) "181" [2]=> string(3) "181" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(15) "William Merussi" [0]=> string(15) "William Merussi" ["course_name"]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" [1]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" ["unit_id"]=> string(3) "227" [2]=> string(3) "227" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(15) "William Merussi" [0]=> string(15) "William Merussi" ["course_name"]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" [1]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" ["unit_id"]=> string(3) "231" [2]=> string(3) "231" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(15) "William Merussi" [0]=> string(15) "William Merussi" ["course_name"]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" [1]=> string(31) "Step by Step Macintosh Training" ["unit_id"]=> string(3) "233" [2]=> string(3) "233" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" [0]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" ["course_name"]=> string(32) "How to become a Powerful Speaker" [1]=> string(32) "How to become a Powerful Speaker" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "1080" [2]=> string(4) "1080" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" } 
array(8) { ["author_name"]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" [0]=> string(10) "tuiuiu_dev" ["course_name"]=> string(32) "How to become a Powerful Speaker" [1]=> string(32) "How to become a Powerful Speaker" ["unit_id"]=> string(4) "1084" [2]=> string(4) "1084" ["unit_quantity"]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: where/how is `$courseList` initially assigned?

Comment: `$courseList = array();` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array()` method check array values, not keys. From your example I can see that as value you have an array with `name` and `seconds` fields.
I think you want to check if that id exists in your array.

So this `if`:

```
if (!in_array($unit['course_name'], $courseList)) {
```

Should be change like this:

```
if (!isset($courseList[$unit['course_name']])) {
```

This way you check if the `$unit['course_name']` is in your array as key.

Comment: That was perfect! It answered my question and taught me some more PHP! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with only values you should use `in_array` function as this example:

```
$array = array("A", "B", "C");
in_array($string, $array) ? "found" : "not found";
```

Else if you have an array with keys you should use `isset` function as this example:

```
$array = array("A" => "Result A", "B" => "Result B", "C" => "Result C");
isset($array[$string]) ? "found" : "not found";
```